# Strange error occurring when using wcf to run query against sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I am building an asp.net application, using II6 on windows server 2003 (vps hosting).
I am confronted with an error I didn't receive on my development machine (windows 7, iis 7.5, 64 bit).

When my wcf service tries launching my query running against a local sql server this is the error I receive:

> Memory gates checking failed because
>   the free memory (43732992 bytes) is
>   less than 5% of total memory. As a
>   result, the service will not be
>   available for incoming requests. To
>   resolve this, either reduce the load
>   on the machine or adjust the value of
>   minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService
>   on the serviceHostingEnvironment
>   config element.

and ideas??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One thing you could try is changing your 'mex' service path to absolute if it is not already. It worked for me once. But that could have been due to the service restarting and freeing some memory.

BrainSlug's Answer has an example of how to do this

Answer (score 151):

In your web.config, in your configuration\system.serviceModel\serviceHostingEnvironment element, add a minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService attribute, and set it to something lower than 5, I set mine to 0, and this error went away for me.

ex:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment ... minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Caution via [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336.aspx): "Specifying this attribute along with partial trust in the web.config file of a WCF service will result in a SecurityException when the service is run."

Comment: @BrianSlugs83 Thanks - this also worked for me in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Is it safe to reduce this to 0%, as recommended in this answer?  Is there a good reason why the default is 5%?

Comment: That's a good question, and I can't say that I know the answer -- but I would venture, that as long as you're not in a partial trust environment, I don't see why it wouldn't be -- on one count, it works around a weird bug -- and on another count, if your server has 0% free memory, you're already having a lot of other, much worse issues. :-/

Comment: Ah heck.  I started getting the "Memory gates" exception on my GoDaddy-hosted WCF service.  As warned by Microsoft, if I try to add the "minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService", I get the exception that "Setting minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService requires full trust privilege"   Damn.  My Service is dead.

Comment: 10 minutes later...  I put the web.config back to the way it was (i.e. without the "minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService" setting) and now, magically, it's working again.  Ridiculous.  Stay away from GoDaddy...

Comment: It's only working because every time you touch web.config you reset your worker process, releasing any memory it was using. You have some kind of memory leak; fiddling with web.config is not going to fix the problem.

Comment: Working on shared host enviroment (mochahost) thanks! - good call to set the webconfig back to how was it(without that freeMin$hit) and should work! Cheers!!!!

Comment: @JoãoBragança Not sure if that was directed at me or Mike. But in my specific situation, I was developing with Visual Studio 2012 and IISExpress, and I consistently saw this error.  It blocked me from being able to develop my web service.  Even rebooting the machine did not help.  Setting this in my web.config fixed the issue for me.  (Mind you, I have a 16 GB machine, and ~8 GB of RAM free when I was seeing this error.)  I think it's a bug in IIS Express. -- As for GoDaddy, it may not be a memory leak, but a Shared Hosting issue.  Either way, for GoDaddy, I would leave it on.

Comment: <serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" >

Comment: This answer saved me, should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when I was running my WCF service locally (localhost). I stopped the service. Closed few apps to clean my ram. and restarted it again. It started normally as earlier.
BrainSlug's Answer also worked. +1 for that. :)
Cheers!!