# WCF service with Full Memory Error (Memory gates checking failed because the free memory) - How to resolve

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service host. My request from wc is high. My host, after a period of time exhibits a problem of memory is full. This problem is repeated. When I open the Web Service help page, this error is shown:

> Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (1398493184
>   bytes) is less than 5% of total memory. As a result, the service will
>   not be available for incoming requests. To resolve this, either reduce
>   the load on the machine or adjust the value of
>   minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the
>   serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

My web.config from the WCF host is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnable="true"/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

and the host web.config is

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaperService" clouseTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisojnMode="StringWildcard" maxBufferSize="1000000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000" messageEncoding="text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1000000000" maxArrayLength="1000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <security mode="None">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorthmSuite="Default" />
  <security>
</binding>
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Just to note: The 'serviceHostingEnvironment' element needs to be a child of 'system.serviceModel' not 'behavior' (as per example in the thread @Andrea supplied)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try setting minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService  to 0 in your web.config for WCF Host, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531518/741695)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Edit 1: this provides a workaround but does not address the root cause. Depending on your specific situation this may or may not be good enough.

Edit 2: as correctly pointed out in comment by @radderz "The 'serviceHostingEnvironment' element needs to be a child of 'system.serviceModel'", see [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicehostingenvironment)

Comment: -1 as this will likely only create a bigger problem (because the service or process is taking 95% of memory, allocating an extra 5% will likely only allow it to consume that as well- then you have hanging processes with no responses instead of failures telling you to check on high memory processes), figuring out what is consuming the memory and addressing the problem directly would be a real fix

Answer (score 20):

instead of changing WCF config value, 
Try to know which process **workingset memory** high, try see that if its really requires

```cs
Powershellcommand>> get-process | Sort-Object WS -desc >c:\process.txt
```

Also to know whether which processid is pointing to IIS App pool

```cs
cmd.exe>> %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list wp
```

By allowing zero in config, this might be able to activate may corrupt the state of service for memory not available reason - that could be not so straight forward in nature :(

My 2 cents...

Comment: +1 for recommending solving the root cause. This could either be solved by reducing the memory footprint of an expensive process (perhaps caused by a bug in some code) or by increasing the resources available.

Comment: Following the `get-process` powershell approach, you can also use the following statement to identify more detailed process info (*window title, peak usage, etc.*)... `get-process -name myprocess | Select-Object * > c:\processdetail.txt`

Comment: Setting this to zero will not corrupt anything, it refers to % physical memory available, not page file.  Its relatively normal in dense environments to have physical memory over-committed.  if your server was out of virtual memory (i.e. page file full) then you'll have bigger issues than just the service not activating properly.

Answer (score 5):

RECYCLE YOUR APP POOL

1. Go to IIS
2. Select Application Pool
3. Locate the application pool your application is running on and select it
4. Click Recycle in the right-hand panel.

[See IIS Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJ3W.png)

Answer (score 3):

There are situations when changing the web.config is not an option. In our case we solved this by increasing the server's memory from 8GB to 16GB.

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs if the RAM of your system is occupied for more than 95%, stop some unwanted processes and try invoking the service again.

Comment: Yes. I noticed that my RAM usage is about 94% of 16GB when this exception occurred. In my case my application is leaking memory.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Resource Monitor on my MS 2008 R2 Web Server to determine that SQL Server was consuming over 29 gigs of my available 32.

After reading others opinions on how much memory to allocate to SQL I set the max memory to 24 gigs. The max server memory limit can be found on the memory tab of your SQL Server properties.

Answer (score 0):

**There could be 3-4 possible reasons for the above error :**

> 1) SQL using most of server space and you have not specified Max Server Memory Limit in SQL Server setting
>
> 2) Your system RAM is fully used.Some program using most of RAM for them to run.
>
> 3) IIS Application Pool is not recycled.
>
> 4) You have not specified "minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService"
>   tag in your Web Service Web.Config file.You can add property in your
>   Web.Config following way.
>
> For Example : minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had a Memory Leak. I would suggest a code revision, instead applying a web.config tweak.