# 404 Not Found error while calling WCF service from Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to access wcf service hosted on IIS from html page using jquery ajax call,I am not able to hit the service , Its throwing 404 not found error, Can i please know should i make changes in the **jquery ajax call** or **web config file** to access the service hosted in IIS or some other remote machine

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="json.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputdata = { "userId": "101"};
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://<ipaddress>/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetUserDetails',
            data: JSON.stringify(inputdata),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //jsonpCallback: "handleResponse",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result.data);
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again.Please check your connection and try again.');
                return;}
});
</script>
   </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Wcf Service :

```
namespace WcfService1
{

    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
      public string GetUserDetails(string userId)
        {
           // Returns User Details 

        }
    }
}
```

Interface : IService1.cs

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         int GetUserDetails(string strUserID);

    }

}
```

WebConfig File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
              <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" bindingConfiguration="crossdomain"/>
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <!--<protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>-->
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >

        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="crossdomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
        <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the another way to go around:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetUserDetails/{strUserID}", 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
User GetUserDetails(string strUserID);
```

And `User` is your custom class holding detail.

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
   [DataMemeber]
   public in UserID {get; set;}

   // Remaining attributes here.
}
```

I don't have much experience with AJAX but I think it should work.

```
url: 'http://<ipaddress>/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetUserDetails/101'
type: 'GET',
//contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", No need to mention it for GET
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your OperationContract,

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetUserDetails", 
    RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,   
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")] 
    int GetUserDetails(string strUserID);
```

Comment: Now its throwing 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Browse and check the service from your IIS

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/govindr/archive/2006/11/01/debugging-wcf-traces-and-message-logs.aspx

Comment: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (123486208 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element

Comment: Try setting minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService to 0 in yourweb.config for WCF Host, as suggested

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880383/strange-error-occurring-when-using-wcf-to-run-query-against-sql-server/11531518#11531518

Comment: If you are just returning results from service, then I will recommend you to use GET instead of POST. And you can specify UserId in URL.

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.

Comment: try WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare

Comment: @Sajeetharan:Thanks for the reply ,  Yes i changed it to   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetUserDetails", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

Comment: Still i am getting Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'

Comment: should i comment the following line of code in webconfig :
              <enableWebScript/>

Answer (score 0):

All seems well,
Need to check services is not giving 404 not found on browser.
If you get 404, you need to [install "HTTP-Activation"](http://iisfault.blogspot.in/2015/04/wcf-svc-404-not-found.html) features under "WCF services" on Windows server 8 or 12.