# JQuery can't find WCF service / 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am using WCF in VS2010 with vb.net. I need call a WCF service method from jQuery.

I have this service: (`CustomerSearch.svc`)

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="CustomerSearch" 
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Classes/Customer/CustomerSearch.vb" %>
```

And I have this interface: (`ICustomerSearch`)

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ICustomerSearch

    <OperationContract()>
    <System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", _
        ResponseFormat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Function GetCustomer(ByVal CustomerSearch As String) As String

End Interface
```

This is my implementation: (`CustomerSearch`)

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.Data
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class CustomerSearch
    Implements ICustomerSearch

    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function GetCustomer(ByVal CustomerSearch As String) As String Implements ICustomerSearch.GetCustomer

        Dim customers As New List(Of Object)()
        Dim objSqlWrapper As New CADatabase.SqlWrapper
        Dim objRsCustomer As System.Data.DataSet

        ...... 
        Return (New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers))

    End Function

End Class
```

This is one part of my html page :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/WCF/Reservauto/Customers/CustomerSearch.svc/GetCustomer",
    data: '{"CustomerSearch": "' + $("#CustomerNameSearch").val() + '"}',
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        strListStations = $( 'Station', data ).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $(this).attr('StationNo') + ' - ' + $(this).text(),
                id: new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr('Latitude'), $(this).attr('Longitude')),
                latitude: $(this).attr('Latitude'),
                longitude: $(this).attr('Longitude')
            };
        }).get();

        $('#CustomerNameSearch').autocomplete({
            source: strListStations,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {

                $('#CustomerStationID').val('');
                $('#MapAddress').val('');
            }
        }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("fixed-height");
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        if (x.status == 0) {
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        } else if (x.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        } else if (x.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error.');
        } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        } else if (e == 'timeout') {
            alert('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

I can browse my service in my browser

[image]

I got this error :

> POST   https://www.dev.reservauto.net/WCF/Reservauto/Customers/CustomerSearch.svc/GetCustomer 404 (Not Found)

```
 m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4
 m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
 (anonymous function) @ AbonneDossier.asp:107
 m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2
 m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
 m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

this is one part of my Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>    
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <!--ASP.Net AJAX endpoint behaviour to enable AJAX calls to the service.-->
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
      <!--<webHttp/>-->
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

<!--Declare that our service use endpointBehaviors-->
<services>
  <service name="CustomerSearch" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CustomerSearch" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: have you tried running this in the WCF test client? can you call the CustomerSearch function in the WCF test client?

Comment: I guess the method should be public..  Public Function GetCustomer. Can you try after setting the method as public?

Comment: @Sushil how can I use wcf Test Client? because when I add my service in wcftest client, i can't see my method?!?

Comment: it should show all your public methods if it is added successfully. if its not showing anything then perhaps your method is not public or you have not configured it properly.

Comment: @Vim : I change it to Public. but it didn't work. and i get the same error.

Comment: @Sushil is what I have to run my project service and after ca use WCFTestClient?

Comment: can you try accessing this method from your code??

Comment: *Most likely*, with the setup you're showing, this is a REST-based service that can be called using the standard HTTP verbs. The WCF Test Client on the other hand is for **SOAP** services - not REST. If you want to test REST, you need Fiddler or a similar tool

Comment: @Sushil : yes I can accessing to this method from my code.

Comment: @Ali Sarshogh: Hi. verify this question please.

Comment: can you post the config? also what type of service is it?

Comment: @Sushil : I put it in my question

Comment: Your contract attribute value and service element name attribute value needs to be fully qualified i.e. namespace.CustomerSearch for name value and namespace.ICUstomerSearch for contract value should be used. This is the reason your service does not start properly

Comment: What is your IIS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution:

I just add `Factory` attribute in `SVC` file.

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
            Language="VB" 
            Debug="true" 
            Service="CustomerSearchService" 
            CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Classes/Customer/CustomerSearchService.vb" 
            Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"%>
```

And I changed my web.Config

```
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="CustomerSearchService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ICustomerSearchService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>


</services>
```

After that it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think your service is true just add **[Serializable]** attribute where you defined Service class:

```
[Serializable]
Public Class CustomerSearch
```

Second, change your Jquery code by this if you sure your WCF address is OK:
Changing from this :

```
url: "/WCF/Reservauto/Customers/CustomerSearch.svc/GetCustomer",
data: '{"CustomerSearch": "' + $("#CustomerNameSearch").val() + '"}',
```

to this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({CustomerSearch: $("#CustomerNameSearch").val()});
```

So I think in your webconfig, at Behavior point needs to change this code:

```
  <webHttp />
```

Finally after your tests, I recommend that adding this configuration individually in your jQuery code :

```
 $.ajax({
           cache: false,
           async: false,
        //    type: "Post",
        //   url: "http://localhost/.../....svc/GetCustomer",
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
```

Comment: I read  this link for check your Behavior Configuration : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530412/make-a-wcf-service-accept-json-data-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Ardalan, this is a sample please check it out . 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Comment: Hi, I did all of you said but it not work. Is it possible that this error is cause with https?

Comment: Did you check it by "Get" option ?

Comment: see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626202/404-not-found-error-while-calling-wcf-service-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: please see this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1807824.aspx?WCF+Service+works+locally+but+returns+404+on+remote+server