# WCF stops responding after some requests

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have built wcf. it is working well

The issue is when I call it many times it displays the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server
>   logs for more details

I configured a WCF Tracing File but it remains always empty. what can be the reason of this sudden stop of the service and how to fix it?

Here is the code that I use at the client's side every 20 seconds:

```
string url = "http://host/Service.svc/method";
                HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                webrequest.Method = "GET";

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

                HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

                Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

                StreamReader loResponseStream =
                    new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

                string strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

                loResponseStream.Close();

                webresponse.Close();
```

Comment: It could be anything, you really need to get that tracing / logging working.  Are there any entries in the Windows Event Viewer?  Also, when you say `"Many Times"`, just how many do you mean?

Comment: does that happen when hosted on IIS but not when run from visual studio by any chance ?

Comment: I don't know exactly this "how many", but I am calling the service every 20 seconds and it stops working in 15 mins approximately.

Absolutely, it happened only when I hosted the service on IIS

Comment: Are you closing your client or letting them all hang open?

Comment: share the code which makes the call every 20 seconds. @Crowcoder is right, it may be proxies that remain open causing the max connection lmit to reach on your service

Comment: Use using block for disposable objects.

Comment: @selami, actually WCF proxy clients are not recommended for disposal. It's a known design flaw. Just `Close()` them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. it was due to open database connections. I missed to close, at the server side, the database connections. Thank you for answer

Answer (score -1):

It could be a working memory issue on the server/host. If there's less than 5% available you get no response.

Comment: So, whats the solution?

Comment: I don't think is the same issue as in this post, but a possible solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880383/strange-error-occurring-when-using-wcf-to-run-query-against-sql-server/11531518#11531518